# how to style certain td in every 3rd table row?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, css-tables

How to select every 4td in every 3rd row?

I have a jQgrid chart and id like to target the client column for every 3rd row starting with first one.

**Here is an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZHRaD/13/

**Basic html:**

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td> // <<
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td> // <<
   <td></td>
</tr>

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rows` property of `<table>` DOM to access `<tr>` elements and `cells` property of `<tr>` to access `<td>` elements. The corresponding code can look like

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var rows = this.rows, cRows = rows.length, iRow, row,
        iSelRows = 0;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
        row = rows[iRow]; // row.id is the rowid
        if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
            // the row is a standard row
            if (iSelRows%4 === 0) {
                $(row.cells[3]).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            }
            iSelRows++;
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding modified jsfiddle demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHRaD/221/).

Answer (score 2):

Use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('tr:nth-child(3n+1) td:nth-child(4)').css('color','blue');
```

updated

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ZHRaD/219/)

```
$('tr:nth-child(3n-1) td:nth-child(4)').css('color','blue');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, little bit of css

```
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4), table tr:nth-child(4n+4) td:nth-child(4) {background:green;}
```

Think i misread, also try

```
table tr:nth-child(3n+3) td:nth-child(4) {background:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(tr:eq(2))` is fined 3rd rows
if fined 3rd rows 2nd column then
$(tr:eq(2)>td:eq(1))

because index starting with 0

Comment: Welcome! I think your answer should actually contain some code. For example, could you implement your solution as a fork of the jsfiddle given in the question?